# AZURE VM CREATION: How to resolve the error, "The selected image is not valid for the specified location. Select a different location."

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

CAN'T CREATE NEW VM.  Its always showing "The selected image is not valid for the specified location. Select a different location." for every configuration.I tried different regions, also different os types.but still it showing the same error:

[image: The selected image is not valid for the specified location. Select a different location.]

Comment: This site is purely about programming. You need to post this on https://serverfault.com.

Comment: The moment I changed my subscription to "pay as you go" this issue went away. Says enough about microsoft really...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate the problem and when I used an existing resource group the validation did also fail for me. However, when I chose to create a new resource group along with the Virtual Machine creation the validation passed. Maybe you should try creating a new resource group while creating the VM.